# How to call google calendar api service using appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I am looking for google calendar api services implementations using appcelerator. How to i will start calling google apis,not getting idea any one please help me.Advance thanks

Answer (score 0):

Declare the network calls using the standard network process http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient  and use the google calendar API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/

e.g. Get Users calendars

```
 var url = " https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList";
 var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
     // function called when the response data is available
     onload : function(e) {
         Ti.API.info("users calendars: " + JSON.stringify(this.responseText));
         alert('success');
     },
     // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
     onerror : function(e) {
         Ti.API.debug(e.error);
         alert('error');
     },
     timeout : 5000  // in milliseconds
 });
 // Prepare the connection.
 client.open("GET", url);
 // Send the request.
 client.send();
```